# Knplabs translatable: How to find an entry by a translatable field?

Tags: symfony, localization, doctrine-orm

I have an entity with the Knp Doctrine behaviors Translatable and Sluggable. Everything works fine so when I create or update an entry there is a slug for each language generated from the title.

The question ist how can i find an entry by a translated slug?

This will throw an error "has no field 'slug'":

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeTestBundle:News')->findOneBySlug($slug);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless someone has a smarter way of doing this then you will need to create a custom repository method that performs a join to the entity translations table to perform your lookup:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * NewsRepository
 */
class NewsRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOneBySlug($slug)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n')
            ->select('n, t')
            ->join('n.translations', 't')
            ->where('t.slug = :slug')
            ->setParameter('slug', $slug);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

I have found that this method works, although I am still curious if there is a more generic solution to this

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
$this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('AcmeTestBundle:News')
->findOneBy(array("slug"=>$slug));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No it doens't help: "Unrecognized field: slug". I think the problem is that there are 2 tables, one for fields without translation and one for translations.
Here is a similar question but with the Gedmo Bundle, there you can use a Hint for the query: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651738/how-to-combine-translatable-and-sluggable-from-doctrineextensions