# Knp Translatable field Repository Entity has no field

Tags: symfony, localization, doctrine

I'm building a site with symfony and using Knp Translatable to handle multi-language administration with Sonata Admin. However, I'm finding myself in a corner so to speak. I have a function to slugify a name but symfony throws an "Entity has not field slug" but the thing is, the field is in my translation tabl as it should.

I already looked at this : [Knplabs translatable: How to find an entry by a translatable field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042423/knplabs-translatable-how-to-find-an-entry-by-a-translatable-field#)

But it did not resolve anything.

Here's my Entity :

```js
<?php

namespace Spec\Bundle\SiteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * Artiste
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Artiste
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="website_url", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $websiteUrl;
   
    /**
      getters and setters
    **/
  
  
    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($method, $arguments);
    }
}
```

Here's the EntityTranslation

```js
<?php

namespace Spec\Bundle\SiteBundle\Entity;
 
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ArtisteTranslation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $description;
  
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255)
     */

    protected $slug;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string
     * @return null
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string
     * @return null
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }


    public function setSlug($slug){$this->slug = $slug;}
    public function getSlug(){return $this->slug;}
}
```

Here is the repo function :

```js
<?php

namespace Spec\Bundle\SiteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\ORM as ORMBehaviors;

class ArtisteRepository extends EntityRepository
{

 public function findOneBySlug($slug){
  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("a");
  $qb
   ->select("a, t")
   ->join("a.translations", "t")
   ->where("t.slug = :slug")
   ->setParameter("slug", $slug);

  return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

 }
}
```

And finally, here's how I call the function:

```js
    public function prePersist($artiste) {
        $helper = $this->container->get("spec.site.helper");
        $slugFr = $helper->slugify($artiste->translate("fr")->getName());
        $slugEn = $helper->slugify($artiste->translate("en")->getName());
      /*
        the helper function is :
        public function slugify($slug){
            $repo = $this->em->getRepository("SpecSiteBundle:Artiste");
            $slugToReturn = $repo->findOneBySlug($slug); 
            return $slugToReturn;
        }
      */
        $artiste->translate("fr")->setSlug($slugFr);
        $artiste->translate("en")->setSlug($slugEn);
        $artiste->upload();
    }
```

And symfony gives me this error:

```js
Entity 'Spec\Bundle\SiteBundle\Entity\Artiste' has no field 'slug'. You can therefore not call 'findOneBySlug' on the entities' repository
```

Comment: I solved it, it was simply because I didn't specify my repository in my Entity. This was a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it was simply because I didn't specify my repository class in my Entity. This was a rookie mistake.